# How to surround a form with an opaque background?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with this code:

```
<form class="form-inline">

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Mail</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Pass</label>
      <input type="password" value='' id="name" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label"></label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: this]

But I would like to surround it with an opaque/transparent write color (saying there is also a bakground image). To give you a better idea of what I need here is an example:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: The images doesn't work.

Comment: Please fix Scrrenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your form a padding to give it more width and height. Then give it a background of white with transparency.
see  sample below

```
.form-inline {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Question above is right. Added padding

Answer (score 3):

Use a background Color with RGBA as below

```
    #form_container {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    }
```

And apply a background image to the parent, for example :

```
body {
   background-image: url('NiceBackground.png');
}
```

Comment: Got it before me! :P I would probably also, just to stay safe, add a z-index to #form_container

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed), if his form is a simple form, z-index will be useless :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg');
}

.form-inline {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54);
}

.form-inline>div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  width: 137px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline">

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Mail</label>
    <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Pass</label>
    <input type="password" value='' id="name" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
    <label for="name" class="control-label"></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
  </div>

</form>
```